# Switch with different colors

Tags: android

i want to make switch that have 2 text color other textOn and other textOff

like this

[image]

how ever i dont know how to reach it and what should i search for in google

so far i have custom thumb

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/notifications"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/notifications"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb" />
```

how to set textoff color and make it background white/transparent.?

```
android:track="@android:color/transparent"
```

does not work

Comment: Use xml in drawable and create a selector in that

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/add_contact_over" />
<item android:state_enabled="false"  android:drawable="@drawable/add_contact_disabled" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/add_contact_default" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this below tutorial link. It will helpfull for you

http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-switch-button.html

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/04/android-switch-button-example.html

http://shitalawathe16.wordpress.com/2013/11/27/switch-button-in-android/